# PHP : SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to access SOAP API with soapClient() , but i'm stuck up with below error.

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: No  element with name '10100/Processes/OrderView/OrderView_v1_0?wsdl'
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\api\soap\client.php
    [line:protected] => 37
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\api\soap\client.php
                    [line] => 37
                    [function] => SoapClient
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://example.com:443/orders/v1/orderview?wsdl
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [trace] => 1
                                    [stream_context] => Resource id #4
                                    [cache_wsdl] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: No  element with name '10100/Processes/OrderView/OrderView_v1_0?wsdl'
    [faultcode] => WSDL
)
```

Below is my code :

```
$header = 'Authorization:'.$tokenType.' '.$accessToken;
$streamContext = array('http' => array("header" => $header , 'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient' ));
$streamContext['ssl'] = array(
    "verify_peer" => false,
    "verify_peer_name" => false,
    "allow_self_signed" => false
);
try{
    $client = new SoapClient('https://example.com:443/orders/v1/orderview?wsdl', array(
                                "trace" => 1,                
                                "stream_context" => stream_context_create($streamContext),
                                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                            ));
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    exit;
```

With php_curl() it's working fine and getting response , But getting error while trying to connect with soapClient.

Answer (score 0):

What does line 37 of C:\xampp\htdocs\api\soap\client.php do? That is probably not where the issue lies, but it might help to understand the error message.

Does it work when you remove the stream_context parameter from your arguments array?

Comment: Line # 37 is soapClient() function . we tried without stream_context also still getting same issue